# How does browsers get WebPush protocol endpoint?

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker, web-push

when we allow web push permission, how does the Browser get the endpoint for push notifications?

When we run this code, we sometimes get a null response (data) in the console. I want to know which endpoint Browser calls to get the WebPush endpoint. Is there any way to trace the problem?

```
navigator.serviceWorker
.getRegistration('YOUR SERVICE WORKER SCOPE')
.then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
            const subscribeOptions = {
                  userVisibleOnly: true,
                  applicationServerKey: 'YOUR VAPID KEY',
          };

          return serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
    }).then((data) => {
          console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
})
```

Comment: Currently you cannot inspect the requests made by the browser to its own push service. They are requests made by the browser, not by your website, so they are not visible in the normal Network tab. If you have issues you need to report a bug in Chromium. In any case it's probably a permission error (are you granting permission?) or network issues (try on a more reliable network).

Comment: @collimarco Thank you, yes, permission is granted. I even sniffed the network with Wireshark, and I couldn't recognize the endpoint address. I think the government has restricted the domain name and I want to get the restricted domain name to report it.